# XML Parsing: Not able to parse xml properly

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML,

```
<toplevel>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahm emanuel"/>
<num_queries int="6350000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="raheem devaughn"/>
<num_queries int="2130000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahat fateh ali khan"/>
<num_queries int="9020000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahab"/>
<num_queries int="1690000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahr brewery"/>
<num_queries int="113000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahsaan patterson"/>
<num_queries int="472000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahul gandhi"/>
<num_queries int="14600000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rah digga"/>
<num_queries int="1180000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahxephon"/>
<num_queries int="1660000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="rahway nj"/>
<num_queries int="3690000"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
</toplevel>
```

This is an output from the google api. I am trying to parse in my android app. I am using DOM to parse it. I have the following code.

```
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } 

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("CompleteSuggestion");

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element suggestion = (Element)nl.item(i);
        String name = suggestion.getAttribute("suggestion");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

I am not able to get the correct attribute value. Its coming empty everytime.

Thx!
rahul.

Comment: String name = suggestion.getAttribute("data");  at a guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion is not an attribute its an element, data is an attribute of element suggestion.
use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element c_suggestion = (Element)nl.item(i);
        Element suggestion = c_suggestion.getElementsByTagName("Suggestion")
        String name = suggestion.getAttribute("data");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```